# printer settings on remote with c# .netcore

Tags: c#, .net-core, settings, printers

I have a function to print labels.
This function configures the printer on the local computer. I want to call this function through an api.
Can I configure the parameters of the printer remotely?

```
            var print = new PrintDocument();

            print.OriginAtMargins = false;

            var printController = new StandardPrintController();

            print.PrintController = printController;
            print.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = parImpresora;
            print.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("", Etiqueta.Tamaño.Ancho,
                                                                        Etiqueta.Tamaño.Alto);
            print.DefaultPageSettings.Color = false;
            print.PrintPage += PrintPage;
            print.Print();
```

Hello, I have a function to print labels.
This function configures the printer on the local computer. I want to call this function through an api.
Can I configure the parameters of the printer remotely?

```
            var print = new PrintDocument();

            print.OriginAtMargins = false;

            var printController = new StandardPrintController();

            print.PrintController = printController;
            print.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = parImpresora;
            print.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("", Etiqueta.Tamaño.Ancho,
                                                                        Etiqueta.Tamaño.Alto);
            print.DefaultPageSettings.Color = false;
            print.PrintPage += PrintPage;
            print.Print();.
```